# S3 PutObject in AWS Lambda (via Node) is doubling filesize when saving to bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been working with http.get and s3.putObject.  Basically, just want to get a file from a http location and save it, as is, to a bucket in S3.  Seems rather simple.  The original filesize is 47kb.

The problem is, the retrieved file (47kb) is being saved to the S3 bucket (using s3.putObject) as 92.4kb in size.  Somewhere, the file has doubled in size, making it non-usable.

How do I prevent the file from doubling in size by the time it is saved to the S3 bucket?

**Here's the entire code used:**

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var imgSourceURL = "http://www.asite.com/an-image.jpg";
    var body;
    var stagingparams;
    http.get(imgSourceURL, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) { body += chunk; });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var tmp_contentType = res.headers['content-type']; // Reported as image/jpeg
            var tmp_contentLength = res.headers['content-length']; // The reported filesize is 50kb (the actual filesize on disk is 47kb)
            stagingparams = {
                Bucket: "myspecialbucket",
                Key: "mytestimage.jpg",
                Body: body
            };
            // When putObject saves the file to S3, it doubles the size of the file to 92.4kb, thus making file non-readable.
            s3.putObject(stagingparams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err, err.stack);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an **array** to store the readable stream bytes and then concatenate all the buffer instances in the array together before calling `s3.putObject`:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var imgSourceURL = "http://www.asite.com/an-image.jpg";
    var body = [];
    var stagingparams;
    http.get(imgSourceURL, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) { body.push(chunk); });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var tmp_contentType = res.headers['content-type']; // Reported as image/jpeg
            var tmp_contentLength = res.headers['content-length']; // The reported filesize is 50kb (the actual filesize on disk is 47kb)
            stagingparams = {
                Bucket: "myspecialbucket",
                Key: "mytestimage.jpg",
                Body: Buffer.concat(body)
            };
            // When putObject saves the file to S3, it doubles the size of the file to 92.4kb, thus making file non-readable.
            s3.putObject(stagingparams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err, err.stack);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome!  The array and concatenation was the fix.