# S3 PutObject Doubling in size when saving to bucket (Java / Spring Webflux)

Tags: api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, spring-webflux

I have a problem similar in uploading to S3 like this one but in Java:

[S3 PutObject in AWS Lambda (via Node) is doubling filesize when saving to bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351218/s3-putobject-in-aws-lambda-via-node-is-doubling-filesize-when-saving-to-bucket)

I'm trying to get binary input from postman and setup the Content-Type to application/octet-stream.

Here is my input in postman:
[image]

Here is my code in the handler:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> upload(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return serverRequest
            .bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class)
            .flatMap(resource -> build(Mono.just(resource.contentLength()), Long.class, HttpStatus.OK));}
```

I tried checking the size of the ByteArrayResource, upon running on my local the size is equal to **368348** (the correct one) but on aws lambda the size is doubled **708233**.

I can upload without a problem when running the app using gradle bootRun, but on aws lambda the file is corrupted.

Are there any setup that I need to make? I've tried adding */* in Api Gateway but it didn't work either. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with standard Amazon libraries?

Comment: How do you integrate API gateway with lambda?